# Why does Google Apps Free require a fax number for a "business" type?

Tags: google-workspace

Is there a reason why Google Apps Free requires a fax number for a "business" type? What if a business doesn't have a fax number?

How can you get around this issue, other than getting an eFax number?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question is obsolete. There is no longer "Google Apps free" and there is no direct substitute. It was a G Suite Legacy, some people might still have a free but others were required to sign up for Google Workspace paid service. In any case, the question is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

I use the free version of Google Apps and have not been required to have a business fax number. Are you sure that you are not mistaken about this "requirement"?

Comment: I'm not mistaken as far as I can tell!  I couldn't get to step 3 unless I entered a number.  Until I was able to get the fax number, I just used my phone number instead and it worked.  But now I can't find the tab where I can change it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you figure out where to change it and want to get a free eFax number, this page has some information on the [eFax free](http://www.faxcompare.com/free-efax-trial-vs-efax-free-plan) plan as well as the [eFax Plus](http://www.faxcompare.com/free-efax-trial-vs-efax-free-plan) plan.